# Dynamically generating row in table with json contents

Tags: html, json

I have a table and I need to fetch data from below json in angularjs,in that table I need to get "id" dynamically from json in `<tr>` of `<table>` when I check on inspect element.
This "id" should come from json "id" attribute below.If "id" is repeating then repeated "id" should come in `<tr>` along with their data. I have able to fetch json data but not getting "id" dynamically.

```
<table id="example" class="display spacing-table" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
        <thead style="display:none;">
            <tr>
                <th>sample</th>
                <th>sample</th>
                <th>sample</th>

            </tr>
        </thead >



        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in names" ng-show="show=={{$index}}">
       <td><img src="images/Project-icon.png">{{x.Name}}</td>
       <td>{{x.City}}</td>
       <td>{{x.Country}}</td>
       </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>

angular.module('TabsApp', [])
.controller('TabsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.show = 1;
    //alert('hi');
    $scope.names =[
  {
    "Name" : "Max Joe",
    "City" : "Lulea",
    "Country" : "Sweden",
    "id":"1"
  },
    {
    "Name" : "Manish",
    "City" : "Delhi",
    "Country" : "India",
    "id":"2"
  },
  {
    "Name" : "Koniglich",
    "City" : "Barcelona",
    "Country" : "Spain",
     "id":"1"
  },
  {
    "Name" : "Wolski",
    "City" : "Arhus",
    "Country" : "Denmark",
    "id":"3"
  }
];    
}]);
```

Comment: Can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Answer

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names" ng-show="show=={{x.id}}">
       <td><img src="images/Project-icon.png">{{x.Name}}</td>
       <td>{{x.City}}</td>
       <td>{{x.Country}}</td>
       </tr>
```